# installing FreeSWITCH on Raspberry Pi VM

Tags: freeswitch

I'm using the first set of commands from here: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Raspberry+Pi

using this Raspberry Pi image:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/

When I run the last command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y freeswitch-meta-all
```

I get the error: `unable to locate package freeswitch-meta-all`

Full output:

```
root@raspberry:~# apt-get update && apt-get install -y freeswitch-meta-all
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/rpi/debian-release buster InRelease 
Hit:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                            
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/rpi/debian-release buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'amd64'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freeswitch-meta-all
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freeswitch.list file in place.
The echo command may fail when preceded by sudo.
Try creating the file as root by entering "sudo su" and the running the "echo" commands in the instructions.

Comment: The file was fine and populated. I ran all the installation commands as root. Ended up just installing it on a Debian VM instead.